# How can I recognize which Ms sql server db use more system resources?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a SQL server 2005 Express ed on my server and have 20 db on it.
I see the Sql server worker process uses many cpu and ram ( 35 - 50 % cpu and 2 GB of Ram)
I think there must be some fault on one ore more dbs. but how can I recognize which db make this problem?

Thanks
Mehdi

Comment: I need to find db system resources usage, maybe only one or 2 dbs use this amount of CPU/Ram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think there must be some fault on
>   one ore more dbs.

I dont think so. 20db's and 2gb ram is quite small.... sql sever likes to cache everything it can, and 20db's are hopefully bigger than 2gb.

35%-50% CAN or CAN NOT be a problem. Depends what the server is asked to do. Sadly, 2005 is old (2 generations bwhind) and the later versions did a lot of progress in terms of finding out what goes on.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952/cpu-utilization-by-database ha an answer to sthis part of the question.

Comment: Have to agree with TomTom - its impossible to know if the CPU usage is an issue without understanding the DB and the app that uses it. And the memory usage seems entirely normal to me - "Unused" memory is memory you wasted money purchasing, so SQL Server using as much of it as possible is normally a good thing.

Comment: thanks for replies. cpu is a Intel Core 2 Quad (4 x 2,4 Ghz) , but dbs for some portals which have about 15000 page visit per day. but how can I check each db's system usages?

Comment: 4 cores and only 2gb ram? The server would be better with about 8gb (2 per core). Get a pro analysing your queries - query profiler helps. not sure it is available for the free express, tough.